Symfony Rate Limiter with additional blocking time option
I need a rate limiter where you can configure a separate blocking time when the limit has been exceeded. The use case would be, for example, that 20 accesses are allowed in one minute, if this number is exceeded, access should be blocked for 30 minutes.
The usual Symfony rate limiters do not seem to support such behavior. Is there a way to implement this behavior with one of the existing Symfony rate limiters or to develop a custom rate limiter based on one of the existing ones?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
